# Injecting an instance bound to the service container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container, laravel-5.1

I have a service provider that I want to use to bind an instance of a class to the service container:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class IcalProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->instance('iCal', function () {
            return new Calendar(config('calendar.name'));
        });
    }
}
```

As I understand [the documentation on binding an instance](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container#binding), this allows me to bind the key `iCal` to the service container so that later in my controller or service class I can type hint `iCal` and the instance created in the service provider will be used.

So I created a controller and tried to type hint my instance:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CalendarInviteController extends Controller
{
    public function download(iCal $ical, $sessionId)
    {
        dd($ical);
    }
}
```

But when I do I get the error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\iCal does not exist

Makes sense, as it applies it's looking for a class named `iCal` in the controller namespace which doesn't exist. There's not a use statement for the instance since `iCal` is just a text key, so I tried telling it to look at the root namespace thinking that may fix it:

```
public function download(\iCal $ical, $sessionId)
```

and I get the error:

> Class iCal does not exist

When I read the section of the documentation on [resolving from the service container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container#resolving) it looks like the only thing I need to do in the controller is type hint to get the instance.

Am I misunderstanding the docs?

### Update

I should also mention that I did add my service provider to my `config/app.php` file.

Also, when I create an interface, bind it to the service container instead, edit the vendor code to implement said interface, and inject that interface instead it works, but that requires that I edit the vendor code which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/container#binding) the method `instance` takes a key and an object instance to register in the container. So, if you want to register a specific instance in the container, the registration should be:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class IcalProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //register a specific instance of the Calendar class in the container
        $this->app->instance('iCal', new Calendar(config('calendar.name') );
    }
}
```

This way you could get back the instance with:

```php
 $cal = \App::make('iCal');
```

If your purpose is to type-hint the class in the controller method, and you want to resolve the previous registered instance from the service container, you could do like this:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class IcalProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //the key will be 'Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar'
        $this->app->instance( Calendar::class, new Calendar(config('calendar.name') );
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//important: specify the Calendar namespace
use Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar;

class CalendarInviteController extends Controller
{
    public function download(Calendar $ical, $sessionId)
    {
        dd($ical);
    }
}
```

This way Laravel will see that you want a `Calendar` object and it will try to get it from the service container looking if exists a binding for this key: (because this is the namespace of the class you have specified in the controller)

```php
Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar
```

and the binding exists! As you have bound this key to your service container in your service provider, so Laravel will return your registered instance.

In the code you provided, you tipe-hinted the class `iCal`, but the class didn't exist anywhere so Laravel wasn't able to instantiate the class

Comment: This: `$this->app->instance( Calendar::class...` was an eye opener for me. I thought when I bound an interface to a concrete implementation Laravel was essentially saying "when you ask for this interface, return whatever follows instead". The line of code you posted made me realize it's really saying "When you ask for this **fully qualified class/interface/whatever** return what follows instead". That difference is huge. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: yes, the method `instance` is not used to bind interfaces, but concrete objects in the service provider (as if it was a registry )

Answer (score 1):

If you’re wanting to inject dependencies into your controller (which is good, so kudos!) then you need an interface name to type-hint on.

Usually you would have a generic interface, and then bind that interface to a concrete implementation. So you may have a calendar service interface, that’s bound to your iCal implementation. Something like this:

```
use Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar;

class CalendarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Services\Calendar', function ($app) {
            return new Calendar(config('calendar.name'));
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['App\Services\Calendar'];
    }
}
```

So long as you register your service provider in your **config/app.php** file, you can now type-hint your calendar dependency in classes:

```
use App\Services\Calendar;

class InvitationController extends Controller
{
    protected $calendar;

    public function __construct(Calendar $calendar)
    {
        $this->calendar = $calendar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Normally I would create an interface, implement it on the concrete class, and then bind it, but the class I was trying to bind was a 3rd party class loaded through composer so I didn't want to add a `implements ...` to the concrete class that would possibly be overwritten during the net composer update. I could create a class in my app structure that extends the vendor class and then implement the interface on that, but that seemed like a big work around for a small thing which is why I wanted to go with the instance. That said, what you you describe is def my preferred method.

Comment: I think you’ve misunderstood: you _don’t_ edit the concrete class (in the **vendor** directory) at any time. You merely bind it to an interface name of your choosing in your service provider.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought the interface had to be implemented on the concrete class for that to work. It's good to know that's not necessary in the service provider.